# Общение клиент-серверного приложения на сокетах Java работает только на одном компьютере

Tags: java, android, сокет

Написал приложение (сервер) на Java и клиент в Android Studio, к серверу подключался  по айпи адресу компьютера (на котором работает сервер) и выделенным портам (8000, 7999) все работало нормально, но только тогда, когда запускал приложение на том же компьютере на котором работал сервер. Перенес приложение на андроид устройство - оказалось что теперь не могу даже подключиться к серверу. В чем вообще может быть проблема?

Comment: Firewall может не пускать

Comment: Как его отключить?

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте. Насколько я знаю, если в качестве хоста вы используйте ip компьютера, то и сервером будет компьютер. Если телефон подключить через локальную сеть к компу может и будет работать, но я не уверен. Чтобы все работала правильно, то скорее всего вместо компа в качестве хоста должен быть какой нибудь хостинг. И сокет должен будет использовать не ip компа, а ip сервера. Я пока, что не имел опыт именно с сокетами в java, но с самой java знаком и этот вывод, я сделал, потому что так работало у меня, с сокетами в python, там у меня была такая же проблема.